# META refresh without 'www'

Tags: html, meta

Hello everyone i need to set up a quick refresh/redirect using **HTML only** so ive decided to go with a meta refresh with 0 second delay. The code i currently have is..

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://my.domain.com/'" />
```

The problem is instead of my browser going to:
http://my.domain.com, it goes to: http://www.my.domain.com

This doesnt work and the expected page does not load.

Is there anyway to force the meta refresh to not add the 'www' when doing the redirect.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that isn't caused by a redirect on the server?

Comment: Does your server redirect to www version?

Comment: i doubt it, because doing the redirect through php (not possible) doesnt add the 'www', and loading 'my.domain.com' in the browser doesnt add the 'www' either

Comment: Domain `my.domain.com` does not exist. The problem is with the real server, and you are not even telling its domain name.